# Copy Channel Doubt (BitmapData class)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am developing an application similar to MS Paint. I am building a Flash Paint application. The basic structure is this.
I have two layers namely topLayer_mc and bottomLayer_mc. The actual vector drawing is drawn on the top layer and onmouseUp of the tool, a bitmap copy of the vector graphics on the top layer is taken and added as a bitmap to the bottom layer. The top layer is cleared subsequently. It is working for the pencil tool.
Now I need to create an eraser tool. This is where things get tricky. In the application there is an option to save the image as png, so alpha has top be preserved. So the coventional method of draw a brush using the vector and using the draw method of bitmap will not work. Of course, on a visual level it would work if the brush drawn using the vector is to have the same color as that of the background.

What I need is to excatly erase the pixels.

The eraser's are rectangular in shape.

The technique I am tring to use is to use the copyChannel method of BitmapData class. Specify a 
channels (say GREEN channel )hex value as 00 and make it as the source. Then make the destination channel ALPHA.

I got it working without using movieclips as shown below.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onMouseDowny)

var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 80, true, 0xFFFF0000);
var bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
this.addChild(bm);

function onMouseDowny(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
    var pt:Point = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);
    bmd.copyChannel(bmd, rect, pt, BitmapDataChannel.GREEN , BitmapDataChannel.ALPHA);
}
```

Just click on multiple points in the red sqaure and the alpha of those points are made zero.

In here the data at the alpha of point of mouse is made to zero . It use copy channel. The swf is shown here.

Link for swf -

http://bobbythecoder.blogspot.com/2011/05/copy-channel-doubt-woking.html

But when I try to use it in the application it just does not work. Of course what I need is a method by much erasing will happen according to mouse move. But for a start I need to clear I paricular point with a desired rectangular dimension.

The SWF is given here :

http://bobbythecoder.blogspot.com/2011/05/copy-channel-doubt-not-working.html

Click on the pencil and then on the canvas to draw using pencil.

The fla is given here.
http://www.easy-share.com/1915107181/Eraser Copy Channel.fla

The code that I am using is this.

```
var gfx:Graphics;

gfx=topLayer_mc.draw_mc.graphics;

var eraserBitmapData:BitmapData;

var bm:Bitmap;

pollPencil();

pollEraser();


function pollPencil():void {

pencil_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onPencilDraw);

}


function onPencilDraw(evt:MouseEvent):void {

topLayer_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onMouseActivity);

}


function onMouseActivity(evt:MouseEvent):void {

switch (String(evt.type)) {

case "mouseDown" :

var initX:Number=topLayer_mc.mouseX;

var initY:Number=topLayer_mc.mouseY;

gfx.lineStyle(1,0,1);

gfx.moveTo(initX,initY);

topLayer_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseActivity);

break;

case "mouseUp" :

topLayer_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseActivity);

var mcBMPD:BitmapData=new BitmapData(topLayer_mc.width,topLayer_mc.height,true,0x000000);

var mcBMP:Bitmap=new Bitmap(mcBMPD);

mcBMPD.draw(topLayer_mc.draw_mc);

bottomLayer_mc.addChild(mcBMP);

gfx.clear();



break;

case "mouseMove" :

var finalX:Number=topLayer_mc.mouseX;

var finalY:Number=topLayer_mc.mouseY;

gfx.lineTo(finalX,finalY);

topLayer_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseActivity);



}

}

function pollEraser()

{

    eraserBitmapData = new BitmapData(bottomLayer_mc.width,bottomLayer_mc.height,true,0x00000000);

        eraserBitmapData.draw(bottomLayer_mc);

    var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);

    var pt:Point = new Point(10,10);

    eraserBitmapData.copyChannel(eraserBitmapData, rect, pt, BitmapDataChannel.GREEN, BitmapDataChannel.ALPHA);

    bm =new Bitmap(eraserBitmapData);

    bottomLayer_mc.addChild(bm);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you doing there, but I did similar drawing board with erase functionality. In my board, erasing is implemented like this:

1. In eraser mode, draw thick black lines on invisible sprite (vector canvas).
2. After each MOUSE_MOVE, draw canvas (only stroke area) to main bitmap with BlendMode.ERASE. That does it - line drawn by eraser tool cuts pixels in main bitmap.
3. Clear canvas' graphics to deal with one stroke at time.

Since your eraser is rectangular, you'll need to treat it like you did with brushes - extend rectangle with mouse movement. The only difference that result of this should be invisible and drawn in erase mode.

Comment: Did you get what I am trying to do in the initial section (not the application code). Just try the swf.                                         I am trying to do exactly the same thing for the swf using movieclips

Comment: I think, copyChannel is not proper erase. You're trying to copy green channel (drawn by eraser) to image alpha. Pixels will disappear, but they will still hold their red, green and blue values. This can be a problem later.